# Why do H and T gates generate rotations of an (irrational * pi)

Tags: bloch-sphere

My quantum information lecture notes state that neither $H$ nor $T$ is a rotation of (irrational * $\pi$).

However it states that both $TH$ and $HT$ are.

Could somebody explain why?

Comment: Without writing out all the math, consider this analogy: when you move _one_ km north, and then _one_ km east, you have moved $\sqrt{2}$ km northeast, which is an 'irrational distance'